# Rails: Not able to save the object after updating it !

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie to rails development.
I have a custom method placed in my Post class, in which I want to update a particular attribute/variable of that Post class. My method goes as below:-

```
def update_bid_winner (winner_id)
  @bid_winner_id = winner_id
  puts @bid_winner_id
  save
  puts "post saved"
end
```

But when I display the Post object , the bid_winner_id variable is still not updated.
I doubt that the object's save is not successful after the updation, because
the puts placed the above method prints the correct value with which I'm trying to update.

Logs from my rails server window:-

```
2      <<< Output of the puts placed for debugging
post saved


Started GET "/posts/1/bids/1/offer_bid" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Nov 21 13:21:59 +0530 2010
Processing by BidsController#offer_bid as HTML
Parameters: {"post_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
User Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
Post Load (3.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE ("posts"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
Bid Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "bids".* FROM "bids" WHERE ("bids"."id" = 1) LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/1
Completed 302 Found in 167ms
```

My post schema as follows:-

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
t.integer  "user_id"
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.integer  "bid_winner_id"
end
```

What Am i doing wrong here ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom method to accomplish this. Rails has a handy method called `update_attribute`:

```
@post.update_attribute(:bid_winner_id,winner_id)
```

which will work, but even that is not idiomatic Rails. If a Post is associated to the BidWinner model, and assuming you found (or created) a BidWinner and assigned it to @bid_winner), then you simply say:

```
@post.bid_winner = @bid_winner
@post.save
```

One other thing -- you aren't really updating this via a GET, are you? That would generally not be a good thing.

Comment: , Thanks for the inputs Man, I would really like to try out the mentioned ways. I'm really new to rails and so just trying things out in my way for now. I'm planning to use a Post , I'll change the get to post. Post is fine right?  I mean it won't have any security loop holes right ?

Answer (score 3):

Use accessor method instead of instance variable `@bid_winner_id`.

```
def update_bid_winner (winner_id)
  self.bid_winner_id = winner_id
  puts self.bid_winner_id
  save
  puts "post saved"
end
```

Comment: Cool Man, that worked. But I need a clarification. I'm very new to ruby, as per my understanding "self" is used in context for class methods and variables right ?. Is 'self' equivalent to 'this' method in Java and other similar languages?? Can you please brief on the usage of self ?? :)

Comment: Rails performs dirty checking (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) and only dirty objects are saved. It only detects dirty objects if if you call methods.